# Запятые в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

*Немаловажную роль в этом произведении играли родители Маши: Иван Кузмич и его супруга Василиса Егоровна. Благодаря им мы узнали, как жили люди в их времена, какие у них были заботы. Также они вырастили свою дочь доброй, сердечной, умной. Комендант и комендантша прекрасно заботились о крепости и её жителях, встали на её защиту в трудный час и приняли совершенно незаслуженную смерть от рук Пугачёва. Из вышеописанного я могу сделать вывод, что Иван Кузмич и Василиса Егоровна заслуживают уважения и являются важными героями произведения.*

Скажите, есть ли ошибки?
Если да, то какие?
Как звучит сочинение-рассуждение?
Может, что-то заменить?
Помогите, пожалуйста, очень на вас надеюсь.

Comment: *=Как звучит сочинение-рассуждение?=* --- Великолепно звучит! Презентовано как сочинение школьника (*Кузмич*). Однако я допускаю, что написано оно специалистом русского языка. Ибо каждое предложение содержит, извините, элементы если не тонкой издёвки, то иронии.

Comment: Интересно,  а в чем здесь заключается тонкая издевка или ирония? Вроде бы обычная трактовка текста.

Comment: Повторяю: допускаю, что писано сие либо специалистом, либо… гениальным школьником. *Ирония* или *издёвка* — это у меня от души, пусть будет *стёб*. Выражен он в тексте особым подбором лексики, почти каждым словом и словосочетанием, например: *играли роль в произведении, благодаря им, также они вырастили, сердечной, прекрасно заботились, незаслуженную смерть* (браво!), *из вышеописанного я могу*… Если принципиально оставлять здесь оригинального *Кузмича*, то и править что-либо нет смысла: налицо авторский стиль!

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, "также" в третьем предложении странно звучит. Получается по смыслу: *благодаря им мы что-то узнали, а **также** они вырастили дочь.* То есть узнали ***мы,*** а вырастили дочь ***они*** — не согласованно выходит. Я бы заменил *также,* например, на *кроме того.*

Answer (score 1):

Немаловажную роль в этом произведении играют родители Маши: Иван Кузмич и его супруга Василиса Егоровна. На их примере мы узнаем, как жили люди в те времена, какие у них были заботы. Простые, добрые  и честные, они и свою дочь вырастили доброй, сердечной, умной. Комендант и комендантша добросовестно заботились о крепости и её жителях, встали на её защиту в трудный час и приняли совершенно незаслуженную смерть от рук Пугачёва. Из всего сказанного можно сделать вывод, что Иван Кузмич и Василиса Егоровна заслуживают большого уважения и их образы, несомненно, важны для понимания идейного смысла повести.

Comment: Sergey, исправил в Вашем ответе "Кузьмич" на "Кузмич", потому что именно так и было у Пушкина.

Answer (score 0):

Это благодаря им, Ивану Кузьмичу и Василисе Егоровне, "мы узнали, как жили люди в их времена, какие у них были заботы"? Странная фраза, снизят оценку. )

Answer (score 0):

Немаловажную роль в этом произведении играют ОБРАЗЫ родителей Маши: Ивана Кузмича и его супруги Василисы Егоровны.